# Sharing service in angularjs between controllers without hitting service multiple times

Tags: angularjs

Currently I am working on project that involves use of angularjs. While developing the module, I felt the need to reuse the data provided by service in two different controllers.

I have a controller `Ctrl1` that hits the `angularjs` service and fetches the data. Now the view `View1.html` that uses `Ctrl1` has a link that navigates the user to another view `View2.html`. `View2.html` uses controller `ctrl2`.

Now I want to pass data fetched by `Ctrl1` in `Ctrl2` without hitting the service again. I have done this using `$rootScope` but I have read that its not recommended. I have also seen many articles recommending to use service but that will hit the database twice which I do not want.

Please suggest.

Comment: Memoize in the service then.

Answer (score 0):

Like Durgpal mentioned - you should save your data in the service.

For example you could have two methdos in the service - fetchDataFromServer, getDataFromNgService.
And a varibale on the service which holds the desired data

```
    var dataHolder = {
      desiredData: null
    } 

    function fetchDataFromServer() {
       $http.getMyData().then(function(yourData) {
          dataHolder.desiredData = yourData 
       )}
    }

    function getDataFromNgService() {
       return dataHolder;
    }
```

ctrl1:

```
    service.fetchDataFromServer(); //fetch data from the server first
    this.data= service.getDataFromNgService();//set the dataHolder on your ctrl
```

ctrl2:

```
   this.data = service.getDataFromNgService();//dont call the server, just set he dataHolder from the ng service on your ctrl
```

and the data is rechable in your html after the call to the server was completed (two way data binding):

```
   {{ctrl.data.desiredData }}
```

hope thats helful.